# Contain string interpolation in a model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, postgresql, model

I would like to create an Active Record object with a string attribute containing string interpolation.

My Schema for the model looks like this:

```
  create_table "twilio_messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

And I have created an object of this model using Active Admin that looks as the following:

```
  => #<TwilioMessage id: 5, name: "weekly_message", body: "\#{user.firstname} you're on the list for this week'...", created_at: "2014-05-29 22:24:36", updated_at: "2014-05-30 17:14:56">
```

The issue is that the string I am creating for the body should look like this:

```
"#{user.firstname} you're on the list for this week's events! www.rsvip.biz/#events"
```

So that the user.firstname gets interpolated into the string and therefore prints out the user's name.

How do I create this type of record without the database automatically trying to escape the interpolation with a "\" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that unless you want to use nasty things like `eval`. String interpolation only takes place in string literals, you can't say `s = '#{x}'` (not the single quotes) and then replace `x` later when you want to use `s`.

There is [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) though:

> **str % arg → new_str**
>
> Format—Uses *str* as a format specification, and returns the result of applying it to *arg*. If the format specification contains more than one substitution, then *arg* must be an `Array` or `Hash` containing the values to be substituted. See `Kernel::sprintf` for details of the format string.

So you could use a `body` like this:

```
m = TwilioMessage.create(
  :body => "%{firstname} you're on the list for this week's events! www.rsvip.biz/#events",
  ...
)
```

and then later, when you have your `user`, fill in the message like this:

```
body = m.body % { :firstname => user.firstname }
```

Of course, you'd have to know that `%{firstname}` was in the string. If you only have a small number of things that you want to interpolate, then you could supply them all and let `%` pick out the ones that are needed:

```
body = m.body % {
  :firstname => user.firstname,
  :lastname  => user.lastname,
  :email     => user.email
}
```

or even add a method to your users:

```
def msg_vals
  {
    :firstname => self.firstname,
    :lastname  => self.lastname,
    :email     => self.email
  }
end
```

and then say things like:

```
body = m.body % user.msg_vals
```

Comment: @Kirti Thanks for the nested quote fix.